# Entity Framework adding existing Child to a new Parent on a many to many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When you want to add an existing Child to a new Parent (1 to 1 or 1-n relation), working with code first, you can just define inside Parent the Child and ChileId and EF automap that id to the child. **Is there any way to do the same on a many to many relation??**

```
Parent
{
  int    ChildId {get;set;}
  aClass Child {get;set;}
}
```

architecture data:
Entity Framework, code first.
Backend webapi/restfull disconnected UI maps a ParentData to ParentEntity Child collection would be something like "countires", so I dont want to add new ones, but just relate many countires to the Parent. There is a multiselect drop-down on the UI, so you can check/uncheck the countries.

e.g.

Parent related with USA, UK

Then at UI someone also checks ESP the 3 will be related to the Parent

Comment: [check this one](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Regarding the comments below my answer: your question is not containing enough details to help you with your multi-layered architecture problems. If you need more than a generic sample solution, you need to provide more details about your specific case.

Comment: done, I added more info. Thx

Answer (score 2):

In many-to-many, it's not as easy to work with ID instead of whole objects.

Consider the following:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
class Child
{
    public Child()
    {
        Parents = new List<Parent>();
    }
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

If the existing child is not loaded (and not wanted to be pre-loaded), you can attach a child entry with ID only to establish the relation:

```
int existingChildId; // some value
var childPlaceholder = new Child { Id = existingChildId };

db.Children.Attach(childPlaceholder);

var newParent = new Parent();
newParent.Children.Add(childPlaceholder);
db.Parents.Add(newParent);

db.SaveChanges();
```

If you don't know whether the child is already loaded in the context and you still want to avoid a database query to load it, inspect the `local` entries:

```
int existingChildId; // some value
var childPlaceholder = db.Children.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == existingChildId) ??
    db.Children.Attach(new Child { Id = existingChildId });

// placeholder is ready to use
```

Comment: OK this seems to be the way I need... but Im getting "{"Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Model.Domain.DropDowns.Competitor' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption\" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.""

Comment: Note the remark *"If the existing child is not loaded"*... otherwise, you need to use the already loaded child entry. Gonna edit to consider this case.

Comment: I already have the child in the collection, and its state es ADDED, and it fails when I try to that state to UNCHANGED

Comment: My child is a drop down, lets say countries, and I dont want to add new countries, but just assign n countries to the Parent

Comment: The existing child should never have the `ADDED` state - this is a separate issue, please explain exactly when the child is getting the added state (debug it until you found the responsible line of code)

Comment: I have disconnected backend webapi/restfull...  UI map a ParentData to ParendEntity, there it gets the ADDED state (new entity)... then later on, on repository layer Im trying to do the magic

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var mathClass= new Class { Name = "Math" };
    Student student1 = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Alice");
    Student student2 = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Bob");
    mathClass.Students.Add(student1);
    mathClass.Students.Add(student2);

    context.AddToClasses(mathClass);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

may be this could help you.

Comment: `AddToClasses` looks more like an EF4 thing... you should consider EF6 or newer as the default for current questions.

Comment: @grek40 have you tried thing like

in my code context.Math.Add(mathClass)

Comment: I haven't tried a thing, but I don't see `context.Math.Add(mathClass)` in your code, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean replace 
 context.AddToClasses(mathClass); 
with 

context.EntityClass.Add()

Comment: Please add an explanation. Code-only answers are likely to be removed by the review process because it's hard to tell what they solve, and how, making them of little value for future readers.